# Buttons inside Gtk.MenuItem isn't clickable

Tags: gtk3, pygtk, pygobject

If I place two `Gtk.Buttons` inside a `Gtk.HBox` and place that `Gtk.HBox` inside a `Gtk.MenuItem` using `Gtk.MenuItem.add()` it gets placed but it's not clickable, the click signals emit to the `Gtk.MenuItem` underneath, the buttons never receive the click signal.
In other words how to place widgets inside a `Gtk.MenuItem` correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600609/can-i-use-a-custom-widget-as-a-popup-menu same issue

Comment: A short snippet of code with what you are doing goes a long way. Trying to reconstruct what you already did is beyond the time constraints must of us have. Read about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).